# Titanium - Android Erase an image

Tags: android, image, appcelerator-titanium

I have a view-1 with a background image and another view-2 on top of view-1 with an image. I need to erase the image in view-2 and need to show the image in view-1.
It can be possible in IOS with paint module. But in android, it's not working.

Here my code:

```
<Alloy>
    <Window id="scratchImageScreen">
        <View id="canvasView"></View>   
    </Window>
</Alloy>

var Paint = require('ti.paint');
var paintView = null;

$.canvasView.backgroundImage = "/images/scratchImage/scratchCard1.png";

paintView = Paint.createPaintView({
        top : 0,
        right : 0,
        bottom : 0,
        left : 0,
        strokeWidth : 10,
        eraseMode : true,
        image : "/images/scratchImage/scratch_card.png"
    });
    $.canvasView.add(paintView);
```

Comment: Please share your code and expected result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with setImage property inside your ti.paint module.You should use a main thread before setting an image.

Do below change in  PaintViewProxy.java module :

```
public void setImage(String imagePath) {
final String imgPath = imagePath;
getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        paintView.setImage(imgPath);
    }
});
```

}